# how to count how many characters can TextView Handle (kotlin)

Tags: android, string, android-studio, kotlin, textview

I've very long text that I want to view as pages so, I have a text view that fulls the screen, and the user can change the size, so after all, I need to count how many characters my text view handles.

I wanted to get the text view Area (width * height) and divided it with text size.

like this: charsCount = (width * height) / textSize
my code:

```
val textView: TextView = findViewById(R.id.textView)

textView.measure(0, 0)
// get textView width
val textViewWidth = textView.measuredWidth
// get textView Height
val textViewHeight = textView.measuredHeight
// get textView textSize
val textSize = textView.textSize
// getChars count
val charsCount = ((textViewWidth * textViewHeight) / textSize).toInt()
```

Comment: Does textView.measure(0, 0) return any value? Because I doubt, you doing measurement in a wrong way. Maybe you can try :

textView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
        MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

or MeasureSpec.EXACTLY

depends on your layout.

Comment: even if I count it manually it doesn't work  I also converted values to one unit,  something is wrong.